# Configure Hive on EMR to include Full Query Text in Logs

Tags: amazon-web-services, hive, emr, amazon-emr

**I would like my Hive Logs to include full query text. Following is the description of my problem.**

I am running a Hive query on Amazon EMR 5.9.0 that has a hive version of 2.3.0.

In my aggregated logs, the structure is as follows:

```
    Containers
        Application_someappid
            Conatiner_someid_00001 /*this would be the driver node*/
                syslog             /*logfile <-- this is what i looked in */
            Conatiner_someid_00002 /*executor*/
            Conatiner_someid_00003 /*executor*/
            Conatiner_someid_00004 /*executor*/
```

The query I ran on Hive via Hue interface is as follows:

```
    select * from myschema.mytable where mytable.x = 'myvalue'
```

In the syslog file i mentioned in the code section above, I can only see:

```
    container_1513263266006_0001_01_000001/syslog_dag_1513263266006_0001_1:2017-12-14 16:17:00,416 [INFO] [IPC Server handler 0 on 36535] |app.DAGAppMaster|: Running DAG: select * from myschema.mytab...=12(Stage-1), callerContext={ context=HIVE, callerType=HIVE_QUERY_ID, callerId=hive_20171214161645_7250360b-3b22-4b1c-a0df-0ce7c163a829 }
```

So basically, the query is truncated:

```
    select * from myschema.mytab...
```

**Is it possible to enable logging of full query text regardless of the length.
Is there a configuration I can set to achieve this.**

Comment: I think you have to look at the Hive server, not the application attempts